# Splitting with RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have some chapters of the first Harry Potter book in a txt file. I want to split the txt file into a list containing the different chapters, without the chapter number and the chapter name. How can I do that with regex?

The txt looks like this:

```
Chapter one

The boy who lived

Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, ...

Chapter two

The vanishing glass

Nearly ten years had passed...
```

So then I want my list to look like:

`['Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, ...', 'Nearly ten years had passed...']`

I am new to regex, but here is what I tried so far:

`chapter_list = re.split('.*\n\nchapter.*\n\n?, text)`

And all the chapter names does not start with **the**

Comment: Probably, you may use `chapter_list = [chapter.strip() for chapter in re.split(r'(?im)^Chapter +\w+(?:-\w+)?$', text) if chapter.strip()]`. The `(?:-\w+)?` is to support words like `twenty-two`. Maybe you can use `[ -]` instead of `-` to allow space instead of a hyphen there.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
re.split('Chapter \w+\n'  ,string)
```

You might get an empty element, but it will be easy to drop it if necessary.

#### Output:

```
['',
 '\nThe boy who lived\n\nMr. and Mrs. Dursley, ...\n\n',
 '\nThe vanishing glass\n\nNearly ten years had passed...']
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want the chapter title to be included. I want it like this `['Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, ...', 'Nearly ten years had passed...']`

Comment: @Kimmen what if some chapters themselves contain the word `chapter` ?

Comment: @Vicrobot That could be a problem, but they don't.